# Avoid geting related entities in EF3.5 one-to-many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

excuse me i have two entities they have one-to-many relation

```
class A
{
    int id;// scaler property
    EntityCollection<B> bs;// navigation property
    EntityCollection<C> cs;// navigation property
}

class B
{
    int id;// scaler property
    A a;//  navigation property
}
```

when i try to get data of 'a' property from B entity

```
using(connection context = new connection)
{
    var t = context
        .B
        .Include("a")
        .Where(v => v.a.id == 10).ToList();
}
```

Entity Framework automatically load 'cs' property collection from database and i don't want to this action happen because in real table there are million rows and this action decrease my performance.

i unfortunately restricted by using version 3.5 of entity framework 
i search two days know there aren't :

```
Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

in this version but in the properties panel i found 'LazyLoadingEnabled' and it disabled and equal false.

thank you for help.

Comment: Excuse me for asking, what is your particular reason of still using an old version?

Comment: @ngeksyo this project working from 10 years ago and it too large and hundred users and hundred gigs databases i need to solve some performance problem and i can't change the technology because customer afraid don't let me and change this need much time and cost.

Comment: In current versions, you declare your collections as `virtual` to prevent loading.

Comment: @SteveGreene does it need to manually change or there are any option in the properties panel?

Comment: It looks like lazy loading was introduced in EF 4. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574253(v=vs.113).aspx). Not familiar with the old days, but it looks like you might need to do something like [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jkowalski/2008/05/12/transparent-lazy-loading-for-entity-framework-part-1/).